# NuGet does not find installed packages: But allows me to use not installed packages

Tags: c#, .net, ide, nuget

I am having a bit of trouble with NuGet.
In VS2017, when I open Manage NuGet packages, it says I dont have any installed packages.

[image]

What is weird that is, that I can use libaries like Newtonsoft.Json, even tough I do not have this libary installed. My packages folder looks like this:[image]

And my references in .csproj look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
  <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
  <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  <Reference Include="System.Configuration.Install" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
  <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
  <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
  <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Security" />
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
  <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  <Reference Include="System.Data" />
  <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So I definetly do not have any reference to Newtonsoft.Json. There seems to be some hidden reference to the libary. Or NuGet is looking for the references at the wrong location.

I have cleared my NuGet cache, tried restoring with Update-Package. When running Update-Package I just get the following message.

> No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'TaskService\TaskService.csproj'.

Why is all of this happeneing? Json is just one example. There are more libaries that are available in my project but I can't anywhere.
Note that my solution contains multiple projects and the other projects work fine.
I can start my project using classes from Newtonsoft.Json. I can build and rebuild without any warnings. But I dont want Newtonsoft.Json. I want it to be nonexistend in my project. Why is it always available in this project (and only this project)? What could be wrong with my project

**EDIT:** After clearing all caches I cant use Newtonsoft.Json anymore (which is good, cause its not installed). But my insatlled packages remain empty. After installing Newtonsoft.Json again, it doesnt have the same symbol like the other references. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: Try doing "Clean Solution" (right-click the solution in the solution explorer), make sure your obj & bin folders are deleted, delete any packages **folders** (not config files) and then open the Nuget console and execute `update-package -reinstall` (forces a remove and restore of all referenced packages).  In short, VS is awesome in so many ways, but sh*t at references.  They just get screwed sometimes and the above steps should be enough to fix most issues.

Comment: @Archer Running `install-packages -reinstall` gives me the following message: No package updates are available from the current package source for project

Comment: Yeah sorry - it's been a while since I did that - I got it completely wrong.  I've updated it now to `update-package -reinstall`

Comment: @Archer Sadly, same result

Comment: Have you checked the packages.config file?

Comment: Also, from what I recall from a mess made by too many cooks on the same project a while ago, there are up to 3 nuget caches.  You may want to make sure you've cleaned all of them.

Comment: Clearing all caches solved one of my problems: I can use Newtonsoft.Json anymore if it is not installed. But my Installed packages in NuGet remain empty. After I install another package, It doesnt have the same symbol like the other references (under references). See my updated question

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.  Glad you've made some progress anyway.  I'm sure someone else will have some ideas and get you sorted :)